# ggplot stacked bar plot with x value and no y/fill value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot with the X axis being time, Y axis being amount, and fill color being certain features.

My data looks something like this:

```
    > base
  Number                                         Mut Time Percent
1   117                                    22:A->G     2   81.81
2    13                                    24:G->A     2    9.09
3    10 22:A->G 24:G->A 108:G->A 158:G->A 162:G->A     2    6.99
4     1                            22:A->G 24:G->A     2    0.69
5    32                                    24:G->A     3   94.11
6     1                           24:G->A 162:G->T     3    2.94
7     1                            24:G->A 82:G->T     3    2.94
```

When I do a stacked bar graph in ggplot using the code:

```
ggplot(base,aes(x = Time, fill = Mut, y = Percent)) +  geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme(legend.key.size = unit(.5, "cm")) + ylab("Number")
```

I get a graph that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/52nE5.png

My problem is I want there to be zero values for time = 1 and time = 4.

Something similar to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rmPW.png

Is there a way I can do this?  Right now I just added 0 values to the data for times 1 and 4 and added my fill feature(Mut) to be one that already showed up in the data:

```
> base
  Reads                                         Mut Time Percent
1     0                                    22:A->G     1    0.00
2   117                                    22:A->G     2   81.81
3    13                                    24:G->A     2    9.09
4    10 22:A->G 24:G->A 108:G->A 158:G->A 162:G->A     2    6.99
5     1                            22:A->G 24:G->A     2    0.69
6    32                                    24:G->A     3   94.11
7     1                           24:G->A 162:G->T     3    2.94
8     1                            24:G->A 82:G->T     3    2.94
9     0                                    22:A->G     4    0.00
```

My problem is I dont want to have to keep searching for a feature (Mut) that is already in the data. is there a way to just have ggplot automatically put x values for time=1 and time =4 with no bar graphs without having to add values to the data?  I have been searching for hours and cant find any answers.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make "Time" a factor. `base$Time <- factor(base$Time, levels=1:4)`. That way `ggplot` will "know" about the missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = 1:4)`

[image]